# Akka wait for computation of actor

Tags: akka

I would like to create a minimal example of an actor that sends off a message to an actor and then waits for the response of that actor. The reason for this example is that I want to use it in my thesis in context of disussing the usage other language features (e.g., futures) instead of pure actors. So the point here is that it **has** to be an actor that waits for a message before processing anything else.

The idea I had was to demonstrate an actor that requests a file to be read from disk, then does some long computation and then waits for the read to finish.

What I have so far is the following:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import scala.io.Source


case class FileContents(content: String)
class WorkerActor extends Actor
{
  def receive =
  {
    case "compute" =>
      println("Computing!")
      // Create actor to read the file
      val reader = context.actorOf(Props[ReadFileActor])
      reader ! ReadFile("/home/christophe/code/thesis-example/src/main/resources/file.txt")

      // Heavy computation
      Thread.sleep(5000)

    case FileContents(content) =>
      println("Got file content:\n" + content)
      // Continue computation.
  }
}

case class ReadFile(path: String)
class ReadFileActor extends Actor
{
  def receive =
  {
    case ReadFile(path) =>
      var contents: String = ""
      for (line <- Source.fromFile(path).getLines())
      {
        contents += line
      }
      sender ! FileContents(contents)
  }
}


object Main extends App
{
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")

  val worker = system.actorOf(Props[WorkerActor], name = "worker")

  worker ! "compute"
  worker ! "compute"
}
```

But what happens here is that `WorkerActor` receives the compute message, and then starts a child actor to read in the file. After the heave computation it receives the second `compute` message instead. And finally receives the two messages from the `ReadFile` actor.

What I actually want to happen is that `WorkerActor` receives the `compute` message, does the heavy computation and then waits until he receives the `FileContents` message. Only after that it can receive any other message (i.e., the second `compute` message).
I have read the docs and searched around for examples but i cant seem to find anything on it.

Disclaimer: I am not using Akka except for this small example in context of my thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is to `keep processing` this message until you get a response. in other words `block`

```
class WorkerActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
     case "compute" =>
     println("Computing!")
     // Create actor to read the file
     val reader = context.actorOf(Props[ReadFileActor])
     val future: Future[FileContents] = 
       (reader ? ReadFile("file.txt").mapTo[FileContents]

    // Heavy computation
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    // this will block current thread and thus the actor,
    // so it will not process any other messages until 
    // future is completed or time is out
    Await.result(future, timeout)   
  }
}
```

`BUT`, this is considered as `a very bad thing` in actor lands.

Answer (score 1):

Just create several ([pool of](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html)) workers for several `compute` messages instead of one worker, smthng like:

```
object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")

  val router = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(2).props(Props[Worker]), "router")

  router ! "compute"
  router ! "compute"

}
```

If you want second worker to be launched after first:

```
def receive = {
  case "compute" => ...
  case FileContents(content) =>
     println("Got file content:\n" + content)
     // Continue computation.
     context.parent ! "compute" //send to the pool 
}

...

//Main:
router ! "compute"
```

Another option is to remember `sender` of `"compute"` (it will be your `Main`) and send the response back to the top-level:

```
var main = _

def receive = {
  case "compute" => 
     ...
     main = sender
  case FileContents(content) =>
     ...
     main ! "ack" 
}

//Main:
(router ? "compute") foreach (_ => router ! compute)
```

If you don't like future here - you may rewrite it with actor:

```
//Main
class MainActor extends Actor {
   def receive = {
      case "start" => router ! "compute"
      case "ack" => router ! "compute"
   }
}
```

P.S. Blocking computations inside actor should be [managed properly](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html) or they may lead to thread starvation.